# Magento 2 - list products out of stock at the end with ELASTIC SEARCH

Tags: magento2, catalog, elasticsearch, cataloginventory

I need to show out of stock products on at the end of listings using ElasticSearch on Magento 2.4.*.

I was able to order without ElasticSearch, but once I enable ElasticSearch it won't work.

It feels like something applies order after the collection orders are set.

Just to let you know:

- This cannot be done using an attribute and enabling sorting because it will be added to any frontend listing at the same time other order is applied;

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Was you able to solve it? I'm facing the same problem

Comment: Hello @jefferson ! Unfortunately I couldn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's happening because you indeed need to change the collection sorting from the ElasticSearch module, in case you use ElasticSuite, there's a customization to do too.

You can use or refer to this module below where you see an around plugin created to "flag" those products during the `Magento\Elasticsearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection\SearchResultApplier` load.

https://github.com/tuyennn/magento2-outofstockatlast/blob/master/Plugin/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/SearchResultApplierPlugin.php

Comment: Cool, thank you very much for your response, I will test that.